# Split and explode a string with different amount of arrays of a pandas dataframe to separate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I try to split a column of text strings which contains comma-separated values (Genres by Song). For further analysis I need every value of the string in a new row. I am new to python. Managed to import the excel in a pandas dataframe. Couldn't find an example of my problem on stack.

df:

| Song Title | Genres | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Song1 | HipHop, Rap | 3:30 |
| Song2 | Rock, Metal,Hard Rock | 2:55 |
| Song3 | Jazz | 4:00 |

What I try to achieve:

| Song Title | Genres | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Song1 | HipHop | 3:30 |
| Song1 | Rap | 3:30 |
| Song2 | Rock | 2:55 |
| Song2 | Metal | 2:55 |
| Song2 | Hard Rock | 2:55 |
| Song3 | Jazz | 4:00 |

Answer (score 1):

Perfect job for `explode`:

```py
df["Genres"] = df["Genres"].apply(lambda g: g.split(","))
df = df.explode("Genres")

# To avoid surprise down the road, remove
# leading and trailing spaces with strip
df["Genres"] = df["Genres"].str.strip()
```